# Changing the scrolling direction inside a scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a swipe navigation using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU

I am creating a book so i have 65 xib files. an example of my code is:

```
    let Pg1 = ViewControllerPg1(nibName: "ViewControllerPg1", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(Pg1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(Pg1.view)
    Pg1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let Pg2 = ViewControllerPg2(nibName: "ViewControllerPg2", bundle:nil)

    var frame1 = Pg2.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    Pg2.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(Pg2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(Pg2.view)
    Pg2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let Pg3 = ViewControllerPg3(nibName: "ViewControllerPg3", bundle:nil)

    var frame2 = Pg3.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
    Pg3.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(Pg3)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(Pg3.view)
    Pg3.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

I have these variables leading up to 65 and then I have:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 65,
self.view.frame.size.height - 66);
```

Everything is inside a `scrollView`

I two problems,
the pages go from the first to the last right to left. However, I need to make it left to right. I need to move between the "pages" using buttons, I have already tried doing so with : `showViewController` and `pushViewController` none of which have worked.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making so many VC variables? Is each class really that distinct? You could probably reuse one VC for everything you are trying to do, and rely on separate instances of that VC to render the content differently.

To answer your question, though, in order to manually page the scrollView, you can use the `scrollRectToVisible` method of UIScrollView to achieve this:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619439-scrollrecttovisible

Good luck!

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot for the answer but i have another question that if you could answer would help me a lot. all my CGRect variables are in a certain ViewController and the button are in a separate one. How could I use them in the function?

Comment: There are lots of ways you could accomplish that. One being that you could subclass the VC that has all of the data so the child could have access. Even better would probably be to design the data so that it is easily accessible in a dataSource kind of object. I don't really understand your code structure, but accessing that data should be trivial.

Comment: HI there! First of all Thank you so much for helping so much already. Secondly I don't know how to subclass  ViewControllers if you could point me to a good tutorial I would be very grateful. I have tried searching online to no avail...Thanks again